# rsync with cloudfuse

Tags: rsync, fuse

I'M trying to rsync between two dirs using:

`rsync -atO --ignore-existing /src 1.1.1.1:/target/`

The target dir is mounted via [cloudfuse](https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse) and the source dir is a regular one.

I get an error:

`rsync: failed to set times on "/target/somefile": Function not implemented (38)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `cloudfuse` doesn't support setting modification times on existing files (the "not implemented" error).

Hence you need to tell `rsync` not to try it:

```
rsync -a --no-times --ignore-existing /src 1.1.1.1:/target/
```

The `-t` you supplied was implied by `-a` and needs to be turned *off*, hence `--no-times`. Also `-0` makes no sense as you're not using *from/filter files.

Comment: it's a capital O, not zero

Comment: also I don't see `--no-times` in rsync's man page (version  3.0.9)

Comment: OK, however `-O` becomes obsolete with `--no-times`; you can find info about `--no-times` if you look for `--no-OPTION` in the man page.